# PHP preg_split is returning empty strings

Tags: php

I am trying to split a string of combined lowercase letters into separate words with each first letter of the word being capitalized. I am trying to use PHP's `preg_split()`, but I'm not sure that I'm using it correctly, because the words aren't delimiters. the options for words are:

```
1. Burger
2. Fries
3. Chicken
4. Pizza
5. Sandwich
6. Onionrings
7. Milkshake
8. Coke
```

The below code returns blank array elements:

```
<?php

$input = 'milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza';
$split = preg_split("/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/", $input);
var_dump($split);
```

All the `var_dumps` and the `echos` are for debugging purposes only. The expected output is to have one long string with space-separated menu items. For example:

```
Burger Coke Fries
```

Comment: Also include the expected output for the same.

Comment: I think you want preg_match not preg_split.

Comment: preg_match didn't quite cut it. preg_match_all does like HoldOffHunger mentioned.

Comment: [`\K` also works](https://3v4l.org/IJq0G). `preg_match_all()` creates a 2d array -- which you don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`preg_split()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will *split* the array by the value you're giving it, just like most `split()`-style functions.  So, of course you get an array of blanks. If you split the string `"-----"` by the character `-`, for instance, then every character is counted as a delimiter and gets scooped out of the string.

What you want is [**`preg_match_all()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

> preg_match_all — Perform a global regular expression match

Store the matches in some `$matches` variable as I do below...

```
$input = 'milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza';
$split = preg_match_all("/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[**Working Demo.**](https://ideone.com/kGliSZ)

Results:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => milkshake
        [1] => pizza
        [2] => chicken
        [3] => fries
        [4] => coke
        [5] => burger
        [6] => pizza
        [7] => sandwich
        [8] => milkshake
        [9] => pizza
    )
```

Comment: The capture group offers no benefit in this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php

$input ="burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke"; 
$pattern = "/[|\s:]/";
$split = preg_split($pattern,$input);
print_r ($split);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture your splitters, but the bits between the splits are empty, though it's possible to discard them.

```
<?php
$input = 'milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza';
$split = preg_split("/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print ucwords(implode(' ', $split));
```

Output:

```
Milkshake Pizza Chicken Fries Coke Burger Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Pizza
```